# Sound compression is on despite volume leveling being switched off in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, audio, compression, realtek-hd-audio

I have an older ASUS ROG which uses Realtek for sound. For reasons I am unable to comprehend, it has begun adding sound compression despite this being switched off in all areas where this might be enabled.

## Settings

### Windows sound settings

[image: Sound: Communication tab]
I have switched off lower volume in Sound → Communication. (‘When Windows discovers communication activity: Do nothing.’)

[image: Sound: Speaker: Properties: Improvements]
All improvements have been switched off via Sound → Speaker → Properties → Improvements. In the same window, sound is currently set to 24-bit 48 kHz; I tried reducing it to 16-bit 44.1 kHz, but it made no difference. Spatial sound is not available.

### Device settings

There are no hardware sound issues found, and what currently is installed, is NVidia High Definition Audio (which has never worked), NVidia Virtual Audio Device (Wave Extensible) (WDM) and Realtek High Definition Audio.

The current version for Realtek HDA is 6.0.1.7874 (6 July 2016).

### Realtek settings

In my Realtek control panel, nothing is visible at all in the AudioWizard, Sound Effects are set to none and volume leveling is switched off; this applies to both the Speakers tab and the Digital Output tab.

[image: Realtek Sound Effects tab]
Realtek Sound Effects tab. The Digital Output tab looks the same. The bit sampling rate is the same as in Windows sound settings: 24-bit and 48 kHz.

## Playback experience

The volume leveling (sound compression) is especially audible on albums such as Elder’s *Reflections of a Floating World*, Dimmu Borgir’s *In Sorte Diaboli* or Frank Klepacki’s live performance at Magfest. All my music is ripped from my personal CDs to FLAC using Exact Audio Copy (except the Magfest show).

I have tried playing back the music both in VLC and Windows Media Player, and it is the same in both. I should further add that sound compression is switched off in VLC. (There is no setting for this in WMP as far as I know.)

## Summary

I have had this issue previously, a few years ago. But somehow, probably with a driver update, it just disappeared. I have no idea what is causing it now, and would very much appreciate it if anyone has any method for solving this. And so, to clearly state my question: **How do I remove volume leveling (sound compression) in Windows when it is switched off in all relevant settings, both in Windows’ system settings, and in the media players I am using?**

## Update

Comment: The first setting only applies when you do voice communication. It will then lower the volume of all audio so the voice call is easier to make. Given that you have a Realtek card, you may need to use their control panel to find the setting that affects this. This can be in Control Panel ->Real Tek Audio or something like that.

Comment: I added this information to my question. Thanks for the comment!

Comment: Try in Device Manager to right-click the Realtek audio device, Update Driver Software, Browse my computer for driver software, Let me pick from a list of device drivers on my computer. If you see a High Definition Audio Device, select this driver and continue answering prompts, finally reboot.

Comment: I have as of present not found any answers that solve the issue, and thus have not awarded the bounty. SE states that I have 21 hours left now that the bounty has expired. Should anyone have any new suggestions, I’m all ears.

Answer (score 1):

To solve your immediate problem; remove all RealTek software and drivers from the computer. Use driver sweeper to remove all RealTek related stuff.
https://www.guru3d.com/content-page/guru3d-driver-sweeper.html

Then try with the default Microsoft driver that is installed after all the reboots. If you are still having trouble, try installing an older version of the driver software from your motherboard support page.

Ultimately, if you are using your computer to listen to music then I would recommend an external audio device (DAC). There are many benefits from physical to software. You don't have to spend a lot to get a better experience. If you get a nice external audio device you can keep it forever, moving it between PCs as you upgrade. New ones come with USB-C so they will be relevant for a long time.

Comment: The tool you linked to is very useful. I followed your instructions to completely remove Realtek, but unfortunately, this did not solve the problem. It may be that it is the hour of the day (I tend to be more sensitive to aural stimulation in the evening), but if anything, it sounds as though it is even more pronounced now than with the Realtek drivers. This has me suspect even more than previously that it is a Windows issue, not a Realtek issue (especially now that there is nothing Realtek installed).

Comment: With regards to hardware, I usually use an external amp and speakers, but it is no good when the output from the computer seems to be the problem. My primary amp though (which is in the living room), can connect to media straight away, so with that sound system I am able to play back the music as desired. That is no good in the office, though.

Comment: 1. Even the "Microsoft" driver is provided by RealTek. It's just the Microsoft approved one.

Comment: 2. I mean an external audio output device (DAC), not amp. You can plug an external DAC in your primary amp and it will sound amazing. If you search for "usb dac" you will see what I mean.

Comment: 2. Ah, sorry, didn’t catch that in passing. Yes, I had the pleasure of listening to some music at a friend of mine’s fed through a tube DAC. It sounded absolutely fantastic – it was like being in the room.

Answer (score 1):

This might help:

- In Device Manager right-click the Realtek audio device
- Select *Update Driver Software*
- Click *Browse my computer for driver software*
- Click *Let me pick from a list of device drivers on my computer*
- Look for "High Definition Audio Device"
- Select this driver and continue answering prompts
- Reboot.

Comment: I was able to follow your steps, but they made no difference (they might do for someone else, though). Same absolutely horrendous volume leveling.

Comment: Try first to delete the device with the Realtek driver.